# Extract a string out of key, value from a text file, and assign to a new variable

Tags: linux, shell, regular-expression, python

Need a script to iterate through below file to read keys, values and extract values eg. foo_key1, foo.com, /tmp/worker${Build_Number} out of key and values assign them to another variable (eg. A="foo_key1", B="foo.com", C="/tmp/worker${Build_Number}").

```
cat abc.txt

foo_key1=foo.com|/tmp/worker${Build_Number}
foo_key2=goo.com|/tmp/manager${Build_Number}
```

I have tried the below code but no luck.

```
while IFS== read -r key val ; do
    val=${val%\"}; val=${val#\"}; key=${key#export };
    A="$(cut -d'_' -f1 <<<"$key")"
    B="$(cut -d'_' -f1 <<<"$val")"
    C="$(cut -d'_' -f2 <<<"$val")"
    echo $A
    echo $B
    echo $C
  done < abc.txt
```

**Expected output:**

```
foo_key1 
foo.com
/tmp/worker${Build_Number}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use awk to split on `=` or `|` and print the 3 columns, then use `read` to assign the columns to variables

```
awk -F '[=|]' '{print $1, $2, $3}' abc.txt | while read A B C; do
    echo $A
    echo $B
    echo $C
done
```

Also you can add a regular expression befor the curly braces to filter the data, for example `'/\S+/ {print $1, $2, $3}'` this uses a regular expression that will match more than 1 character that is not a whitespace thus skipping blank lines

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
while IFS='|=' read A B C ; do
  echo "$A"
  echo "$B"
  echo "$C"
done < abc.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would benefit from these revisions:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat abc.txt | while IFS= read -r line ; do

A=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/=/ /g;s/|/ /g' |  awk '{print $1}')
B=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/=/ /g;s/|/ /g' |  awk '{print $2}')
C=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/=/ /g;s/|/ /g' |  awk '{print $3}')

    echo $A
    echo $B
    echo $C
  done

foo_key1
foo.com
/tmp/worker${Build_Number}
foo_key2
goo.com
/tmp/manager${Build_Number}
```